# problem with Chrome extension background file

Tags: javascript, html, dom, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

```js
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Inglesando  - The Word Catcher",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Amplie o seu vocabulário capturarando palavras em inglês como se tivesse capturando pokémons.",
    "permissions": ["contextMenus", "storage"],
    "action": {
      "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "background": {
      "service_worker": "background.js",
      "persistent": true
    },
    "icons": {
      "16": "images/flag.png"
    }
  
  }
```

I am trying to make a google extension to catch words in english from different websites, but, when I right click in the context menu and try to add this word to my extension, nothinng happens. Like, when the inspect view is in "Inactive" mood it  and user click on my extension icon to popup information it never shows anything. i have to click on the console page and click in the top extension or maybe change it to background extension (which is my extension) to make it active. How can i make it action in an active mood all the time? [image] [image]

What should I do to solve it?

```js
//popup.js file
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
    let text = request.text;
    
    // Check if the message contains the 'text' property
    try {
        if (text !== undefined) {
            const wordOfList = document.getElementById("wordList");
            if (!wordOfList) return;
            const list = document.createElement('li');
            // Increment a counter for each word
            if (!wordOfList.dataset.counter) { 
                wordOfList.dataset.counter = 1;
            } else {
                wordOfList.dataset.counter++;
            }

            // Concatenate the counter with the text content
            list.textContent = wordOfList.dataset.counter + ' - ' + text;
            wordOfList.appendChild(list);
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

```
//background.js
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(genericOnClick); //It listens for clicks on context menu items and calls the genericOnClick function when an item is clicked.

function genericOnClick(info) { //The info parameter contains information about the clicked item
      // Standard context menu item function

      let text = info.selectionText;
      console.log(`Selected text: ${text}`);

      // Send the words for the popup
      chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ text });

};


// This event is triggered when the extension is installed or updated.
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function () {
  // Create one test item for each context type.
  let contexts = [
    'page',
    'selection',
    'link',
    'editable',
    'image',
    'video',
    'audio'
  ];
  for (let i = 0; i < contexts.length; i++) {
    let context = contexts[i];
    let title = "Inglesando  - Add word";
    chrome.contextMenus.create({
      title: title,
      contexts: [context],
      id: context,

    });
  }
 });
```

```html
<!-- popup.html -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Inglesando  - The Word Catcher</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="popup.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;500;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="content">
        <h3>Adicione novas palavras</h2>
        <img src="./images/extension-icon.png" id="iconImage">
    </div>

    <p>Suas palavras:</p>
    
    <ul id="wordList"></ul>

    <script src="popup.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: Please also share your manifest.json configs.

Comment: Did you add the following to your manifest.json? 
"background": {
  "scripts": ["background.js"],
  "persistent": false // or true, depending on your needs
},

Comment: oh, sorry! I forget to share my manifest.json file. I tris to add like this"background": {
      "service_worker": "background.js",
      "persistent": true
    }
but apparently manifest v3 don't accept "persistent", because it gives an error  and I can't even run the extension

Comment: The problem is that the popup doesn't run when it's not shown so it can't receive the message. Either don't use contextMenu at all (just click the extension icon: [example](/a/68543098)) or instead of the popup add your UI into the web page as a DOM element. P.S. `persistent`  and `scripts` is for ManifestV2.

Comment: @wOxxOm can you give me an example of what you are trying to say, please?

Comment: See the link in my comment.

Comment: thanks, I solved my problem  :)